# Apache Jena querying: Too complex or not too complex

Tags: query-optimization, sparql, jena, wikidata

I have the following data in my database:

```
@prefix geo: <http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#> .
@prefix p: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/> .
@prefix ps: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/statement/> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/> .
@prefix wds: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/statement/> .
@prefix wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/> .

wd:Q4472 rdfs:label
        "Aulesti"@en ;
    p:P625 wds:q4472-589D5F6B-FC8C-4584-9546-89A2930F141A ;
    wdt:P625 "Point(-2.5628139 43.296423)"^^geo:wktLiteral .

wds:q4472-589D5F6B-FC8C-4584-9546-89A2930F141A ps:P625 "Point(-2.5628139 43.296423)"^^geo:wktLiteral .
```

As you can see, the location information exists twice. It's a sample from Wikidata, where that happens quite often. But sometimes only one of them exists, and it is not known which one.

So normally I would collect them with the following query:

```
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/> 
PREFIX p: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/> 
PREFIX ps: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/statement/> 

SELECT ?place ?coord WHERE { 
  ?place wdt:P625 ?coord
  OPTIONAL {
    ?place p:P625 ?itemLocation .
    ?itemLocation ps:P625 ?coord .
  }
}
```

As a human, I would take the shortest path and when there is no `?coord`, I have to go the long route down over `?itemLocation`.

Which strategy is used by Jena?

Is it a suitable way to get the same result value from two different relations?

Should I query twice?

Do you have another option?

Comment: OPTIONAL is a left-join. Technically, the query algebra is as follows: `(project (?place ?coord)
      (leftjoin
        (bgp (triple ?place wdt:P625 ?coord))
        (bgp
          (triple ?place p:P625 ?itemLocation)
          (triple ?itemLocation ps:P625 ?coord)
        )))))`  There is nothing what you call "strategy to fill a value". Your query is the typical way how to work, the triple patterns will be evaluated all. Query can be shortened: `OPTIONAL ?place p:P625/ps:P625 ?coord }

Comment: There are concepts like `IF`, `EXISTS`, `COALESCE` etc. But I don't know if it's worth to think about something complicated. Do you have any performance issues or why are you asking?

Comment: Read  about the [Wikidata data model](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format). There is even longer "path": `p:P625/ps:P625/psv:P625/wikibase:geoLongitude`. BTW, I'm not sure it is possible that `wdt:P625` exists whereas `ps:P625`  doesn't. Have you an example?

Comment: @StanislavKralin I do not know an entity, which did not have a psv/geo or wds/geo when a p:P625 exists.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what data you want. I think that if you want the most relevant value(s) you should use only `?place wdt:P625 ?coord`. See the explanation in the following.

The prefix `wdt` stands for the [direct relationship](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/SPARQL/Prefixes) `PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>`; this is related to the way the **Wikidata** represents knowledge. Wikidata is not originally in RDF format, hence, some modeling approach should be adapted to represent these data in RDF.

The [method](http://korrekt.org/papers/Wikidata-RDF-export-2014.pdf) used is in some sense, similar to RDF reification where you might need to add (meta)information to statements (triples) of the form `s p o`, for example, the source, the author, the time of the statement and so on. Wikidata needs a way to establish an ordering between the multiple values of multi-valued properties. For example, the *population* of the US might have been issued in 2008 to 290 Millions for example and 2016 to 310 Millions. Thus, a population property might have two different values. Wikidata gives a [ranking](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Help:Ranking), that prefers the 2016 value (310) to the 2008 (290) value when querying for the direct values. When you use `wdt` prefix with property name, you query for direct values, which have the highest ranking between other (you should read [this](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Help:Ranking)). Otherwise (`p` prefix), you match against the customized Wikidata model to represent data in RDF, see for example [this query](https://query.wikidata.org/#%23added%20before%202016-10%0ASELECT%20%3Fcountry%20%3FcountryLabel%20%28count%28%2A%29%20AS%20%3Fcount%29%0AWHERE%0A%7B%0A%09%3Fcity%20wdt%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279%2A%20wd%3AQ515%20.%20%23%20find%20instances%20of%20subclasses%20of%20city%0A%09%3Fcity%20p%3AP6%20%3Fstatement%20.%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20with%20a%20P6%20%28head%20of%20goverment%29%20statement%0A%09%3Fstatement%20ps%3AP6%20%3Fmayor%20.%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20...%20that%20has%20the%20value%20%3Fmayor%0A%09%3Fmayor%20wdt%3AP21%20wd%3AQ6581072%20.%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20...%20where%20the%20%3Fmayor%20has%20P21%20%28sex%20or%20gender%29%20female%0A%09FILTER%20NOT%20EXISTS%20%7B%20%3Fstatement%20pq%3AP582%20%3Fx%20%7D%20%20%23%20...%20but%20the%20statement%20has%20no%20P582%20%28end%20date%29%20qualifier%0A%09%3Fcity%20wdt%3AP17%20%3Fcountry%20.%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20Also%20find%20the%20country%20of%20the%20city%0A%20%09%0A%09%23%20If%20available%2C%20get%20the%20%22ru%22%20label%20of%20the%20country%2C%20use%20%22en%22%20as%20fallback%3A%0A%09SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%0A%09%09bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22ru%2Cen%22%20.%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3Fcountry%20%3FcountryLabel%0AORDER%20BY%20DESC%28%3Fcount%29%0ALIMIT%20100).

When you query for a property using `wdt` prefix, you get two benefits; first you skip the exhaustive syntax to access properties as subjects, and you get for each property the best ranking value. And this is also performance-wise decision, I think.